# Command not found: PHP exec()

Tags: php, node.js, shell

This is driving me crazy. I need to have php execute a command to restart a script running in node. I'm using a node app called forever to run said script. The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
  echo '<pre>';
  echo exec('sudo -u dalton forever restart botti.js 2>&1');
  echo '</pre>';
?>
```

However, when I run that, I get `sudo: forever: command not found`

Next, I try `which forever` and `type forever`, both which give me:
`forever: /usr/local/bin/forever`

I edit my code to:
`echo exec('sudo -u dalton /usr/local/bin/forever restart botti.js 2>&1');`

Edit: After a typo, the error is now:
`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

I'm at my wit's end. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, `/user/...` should be a typo of `/usr/...`?

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed that. Now the error is `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Comment: The exec function is a dangerous function, should not be used and be disabled in your php.ini. Using exec to solve problems of your web application is not the right way.

Comment: If I could think of another way to restart a node script via the web, I'd do it. But nothing comes to mind.

Comment: I might need to add that what I'm saying applies for web applications, not for console apps of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to define node as well:

`$asdf = system('sudo -E -u dalton /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/forever restart botti.js  2>&1');`

Answer (score 7):

As the `forever` command only runs, when you give the full path, I suspect, that `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `PATH` environment variable, which contains all directories, that are searched for executable commands by default, separated by `:` (I suspect you're on Linux, may differ for other OS)

I suspect `forever` calls `/usr/bin/env node`. The error from `env` is probably caused by `node` being outside your `PATH` too.

To set your PATH in php, use `putenv('PATH=<your path here>');`
e.g. to append `/usr/local/bin`:

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin')
```

This may also be a `sudo` issue, try the `-E` (preserve environment) switch.

Comment: Added that line, and then removed the /usr/local/bin prefix to forever, and I reverted back to the forever not found error.

Comment: Same for `echo exec('export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin; sudo -u dalton forever restart botti.js  2>&1');`

Comment: have you tried `sudo -E`? sudo may be configured to reset the PATH, in that case you would have to change the PATH inside your `forever` script EDIT: ah, I see you figured it out. Anyway, still seems like PATH is wrong

Comment: I know, and I'm still trying to figure it out, but this sloppy bit of code works for now. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link for forever

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/forever /usr/bin/env/forever
```

And also for nodejs if incase it's still called "nodejs". Make it call as "node"

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

I will solve the forever execution problem.

For php side, try with this

```
echo shell_exec("your command sh");
```